# App can't be moved to SD card

Tags: sd-card, htc, app2sd

There was an app moved to SD card.

I did a factory reset.
Then I reinstalled the app. It was side loaded by Humble Bundle app, it's not from Google Play.

Now the app can't be moved to SD, getting error "Couldn't move app".

I am guessing there is this some type of Android's cache for this app on SD already that prevents it from moving again, but this is just a speculation.

Titanium backup couldn't move it either. Well, it said it did but it's still "on the phone".

Any ideas welcome.

The phone is HTC Sensation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You most probably left some residuals of the (moved) app on your SD card.

The easiest way to remove that would probably to pull out the SD card and remove the moved app on your computer (it's not accessible on your phone easily).

For example, the full path to the moved tricorder app on my phone is:
/mnt/sdcard/.android_secure/org.hermit.tricorder-1.asec

Just access it on your PC and remove the appropriate .asec file in the .android_secure folder.

Background (why not to do it on the phone):

Moved Apps are located in a cryptoloop mounted container file which is stored at /mnt/sdcard/.android_asec/*. This is however not accessible so that normal apps cannot mess around with moved apps (there's a tmpf mounted over /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure with 0kb space to inhibit access). The original .android_secure is bind mounted to /mnt/asec/secure where the system can access the containers.

```
app_36@android:/ $ mount 
# omitted unecessary stuff, only the sdcard, the bind mount and the tmpfs mount are shown 
/dev/block/vold/254:1 /mnt/sdcard vfat [mount-options-omitted] 0 0
/dev/block/vold/254:1 /mnt/secure/asec vfat [mount-options-omitted] 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure tmpfs [mount-options-omitted] 0 0 
# no output, tmpfs still mounted:
app_36@android:/mnt/sdcard/.android_secure # ls
app_36@android:/mnt/secure/asec # umount /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure
# umounted... now there's what we expect:
app_36@android:/mnt/secure/asec # cd /mnt/sdcard/.android_secure
app_36@android:/mnt/sdcard/.android_secure # ls
org.hermit.tricorder-1.asec
```

Comment: +'d, Exactly my thoughts on this issue! :)

Comment: Yeah, not tried it but it must just be this. PS: If you want to do it on the phone, you need root to umount the tmpfs mount (as shown above), then just remove the .asec file using any file explorer you have installed.

Comment: This was the right move. I deleted entire /.android_secure (since I reset the phone anyway). Now I can move almost everything I want to SD without an error. However the app in question still can't be moved. Since it solved the issue for most apps I'll go ahead and mark it resolved but I'd appreciate any further info. Thanks.

Comment: Good question. I have only less constructive ideas left. What say the logs: [logcat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.logcat). Else, standard procedure proposal: Reinstalled app and retried? Is it a paid (protected) app that cannot be moved?

Comment: @ce4: Thank you for this detailed answer! Not that I was affected by the problem, but now I better understand how `/sdcard/.android_secure` and `/mnt/secure/asec` work together, technically speaking.

Comment: Reinstalled app and retried - yes, a few times, same result. Logcat is awesome, thanks. Interestingly the log shows "Failes to unlink asec '/mnt/secure/asec/appname.asec' (No such file or directory)". Weird, of course it's not there. Tried to create an empty file with the same name, still can't be moved. Then there was this: "No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/app/appname.apk". I am guessing something is wrong with permissions. I'll look into this further. Thanks for a lot of useful info.

Answer (score 0):

When I had an N1 that used to fill up on space quickly, I used to use an app called [ModInstallLocation](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=778738) to move apps that weren't technically movable through Apps2SD.

[image]

Comment: As it turns out ModInstallLocation didn't help, app was still installed on the phone. Apps2SD opens the standard Android app info page that has the "Move to SD" button which fails with "Couldn't move app".